# how could I check ( listener) whether torch is on or off by default in android? i know hot to open or off torch but is there any listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, flashlight

```
val cm=getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val cameraID=cm.cameraIdList[0]
cm.setTorchMode(cameraID,true)
```

I want to open torch if it was not opened by user with their default torch app or widget.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am not unfortunately able to help you to get an answer, but I was wondering whether it would be easier to find your question for others in the future and help more people if the title of the question was something like `Is there any listener for checking whether torch is on or off in Android?`. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

[Read the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#registerTorchCallback(android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.TorchCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

> `public void registerTorchCallback (CameraManager.TorchCallback callback, Handler handler)`
>
> Register a callback to be notified about torch mode status.
>
> Registering the same callback again will replace the handler with the
> new one provided.
>
> The first time a callback is registered, it is immediately called with
> the torch mode status of all currently known camera devices with a
> flash unit.
>
> Since this callback will be registered with the camera service,
> remember to unregister it once it is no longer needed; otherwise the
> callback will continue to receive events indefinitely and it may
> prevent other resources from being released. Specifically, the
> callbacks will be invoked independently of the general activity
> lifecycle and independently of the state of individual CameraManager
> instances.